# Heavy lag with Grease Pencil Line Art

Tags: modeling, eevee-render-engine, lineart

I've been experiencing heavy lagging when I have multiple objects using Grease Pencil line art. I can orbit around the scene pretty well at around 30fps. However, when I move objects with line art, it lags to the point where I can't drag it around at more than 1 or 2 frames per second. It's crashed Blender a couple times.

It happens in every viewport mode (wireframe, solid, material, rendered). It's on Eevee, and switching to Cycles or Workbench doesn't help either.

I'm on a 2019 MacBook Pro 16" i7, Radeon Pro 5330M, 16GB RAM. Sometimes I work while connected to a 4K monitor at 60Hz, so that might have something to do with it, but I'm not sure.

[image]

[Here's the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1axO8VeVGFP1z2JTC0cVgOzT3jprZ_4Id/view?usp=sharing) Tysm for any help you can provide.